# Is there a way to read .dat file in java and have it stored in a int array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have seen some similar post in the past that have helped me with the .dat file however I am still stuck on the integer array part. So I have a .dat file with ten numbers 1-10. I can read the integers in with DataInputStream and write it out again using DataOutputStream just fine. I also want to put the ten integers from the .dat file into an int[] array. When I debug, I understand it is not reading in as "integers" right, if I put a print statement and I see it prints to the console something like "840966176". So since I'm new to programming, how do I go about converting what is read from the input into integer to be placed into the int []?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        int arrayCount=0;
        int[] intArray = new int[20];
        in = new File(args[0]);
        outfile = new File(args[1]);
        input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(in));
        out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outfile, true));

        while (input.available() > 0) {
            n = input.readInt();
            intArray[arrayCount] = n;
            
            out.writeInt(n);
            arrayCount++;
            
        } 
        
         input.close();
         out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no *standard* that specifies what a `.dat` file might contain. Raw binary data, or some data in a specific proprietary format? In other words: the real question is: what is your expectation/requirement what kind of data sits in your .dat file?!

Comment: Any implementation is dependent upon the form of the data in the file being read.  Java provides a number of facilities for parsing data from streams so you don't have to muddle with the bytes.  Take a look at the BufferedReader and Scanner classes.